# How to install burg bootloader in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, bootloader, burg

Tried many ways, but it seems a dead end.

Tried the installation method for Ubuntu 16.04 but it keeps giving errors.

Comment: AFAIK it has been about a decade since there's any update for BURG. Which installation method did you try and which errors you got? Please [edit] your question to add them.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed burg on Ubuntu 20.04 this week and it works well.
It is meant for PCs with BIOS - Not for UEFI Installations!

1. Download burg files - Do not use synaptic !
   I got the files from:
   [https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/ubuntu/burg/+packages](https://launchpad.net/%7En-muench/+archive/ubuntu/burg/+packages)
   They are:

   ```
   burg-common_1.98+20100623-2.3_amd64.deb (1021.8 KiB) 
   burg-emu_1.98+20100623-2.3_amd64.deb (1.3 MiB) 
   burg-pc_1.98+20100623-2.3_amd64.deb (683.5 KiB) 
   burg_1.98+20100623-2.3_amd64.deb (9.5 KiB) 
   burg-themes-common_1.98+20100623-2_all.deb (3.4 MiB)
   burg-themes_1.98+20100623-2_all.deb (6.4 MiB)
   ```
2. Install dependencies.
   In terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install base-files dpkg libfreetype6 zlib1g gettext-base libncurses5 libsdl1.2debian debconf
   ```
3. Install the burg packages.
   Move all 6 of them into an empty folder.
   Inside that folder open terminal and install with:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

   It will ask where to install it to: `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`
   I answered the drive that hasn't got a bootlader yet.
   It is safe to do if you have two hard drives.
   Say you are using grub on `/dev/sda`;
   then we install burg to `/dev/sdb`

   In my case this needed to be done again before reboot
   In terminal:

   ```
   sudo burg-install /dev/sdb
   ```
4. Update burg.
   In terminal:

   ```
   sudo update-burg
   ```
5. Test with Burg Emulator.
   In terminal:

   ```
   burg-emu
   ```

   Now we see the result as we see it at the boot-up screen.
   My first test showed only text like grub.
   It finally showed a graphical screen
   when I copied all 200 files from the newly installed folder:

   ```
   /usr/lib/burg/i386-pc/ to folder: /boot/burg/
   ```

   And then did the update command again:

   ```
   sudo update-burg
   ```

   I also have a folder in `/boot/burg/` called: `locale`,
   which I copied from a previous burg install in xenial.
   It contains: `de.mo  en_AU.mo  en_CA.mo  en_GB.mo`
   It looks like it had been compiled by an application
   as these are the languages I installed.

   Somehow there must be another burg command to use
   that I missed out on.
   Anyway it works for me; I'm very pleased
6. Setup BIOS.
   Then after installation, we reboot
   and go into the BIOS > Boot Order
   and set it to `/dev/sdb`
7. The result.
   If it works you can change the theme via the <kbd>F2</kbd> key.
   It is better not to touch the <kbd>F3</kbd> key resolution.
   If it doesn't work we can always change
   the BIOS boot order to as it was before.

I created a couple of themes and new icons.
I intend to publish on my site page:
https://www.pling.com/u/fenario/
Check it out in a week or so

In the meantime you can get my burg folder and pick what you need

My whole folder: `/boot/burg/` is available for download at:
https://mega.nz/file/TKpAXRxJ#lV6XTeQnA_wKZXQo20M9t7F9E8gkozVIHncn-bm8UIc
It contains my themes and new icon classes

A picture of my burg boot-screen menu is available for download at:
https://mega.nz/file/na4UQLJD#r-0RX8mssEprGSclWqJOj06bJRzVdmW4sCSpj2GSiJs

[image: burg boot-screen menu]